# How can I trace a Web Service?

Tags: web-services, abap

I have a Web Service that sends data from SAP to a external system (non-SAP, lets cal it X).

If I run the Function Module (of the WS) in `SE37` or the WS in `SE80` (Test Service definition) it returns a result (the correct result) but if a user calls the Web Service from system X, the result will differ.

In both scenarios the same parameters are used.

Is there a way to trace the user who calls the Web Service from system X ?

For example, every time a user calls the Web Service from system X, a system user from SAP runs the Function Module from the WS and I could trace that system user.

Comment: It's been a while but I think what you are looking for is ST12? Here you can trace the activity of function modules.

Comment: I did not know I can trace by function module and not by user. I will give it a try.

Comment: if you need to trace called FM separately you need to set [external breakpoint by system user](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56a77c1b25981d11f5774bbe/t/57c5cee5d1758ecd49f4982c/1472581353223/?format=1500w) which calls this FM. The user for debugging can be checked in `SRT_ADMIN` tcode (by default it's `SAP_WSRT`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **SRT_UTIL** or **SRTUTIL** t-code for Tracing Utilities for Web Service. You need to enable tracing by user.

[image: Trace configuration]

NOTE: If your system older (like ECC 6) you cannot find these t-codes.